# How can I change an Object instance and return a value from in the same method?

Tags: java, object, methods, instance

I have problem to handle a particular method with a custom Object:

I made a Class "NodeQueue" that contains a list of Nodes (SList<"Node">), its length and the first element of the list

```
private final SList<Node> q;
private final int length;
private final Node first;

public NodeQueue()                              //Empty queue
{
    q      = new SList<Node>();
    length = 0;
    first  = null;
}

public NodeQueue(SList<Node> q1)             //Full queue
{
    q      = q1;
    length = q.length();                     //length() is the method that returns the length of SList<T>
    first  = q.car();                        //car() is the method that returns the first element of SList<T>
}

public Node poll()
{
    ...

    return first;
}
```

Where the expected function of poll() is the following one:

```
NodeQueue n = new NodeQueue();  //Let's pretend n is not empty

Node a = n.poll();              //Where "a" is the first element of the list
```

The issue is that in "poll()" I need to return the first element (in this case to Node a) and erase it from the the actual instance of "NodeQueue n".

How am I supposed to update Nodequeue and return the first element in a single function?

I basically need to set "Node a" to the first element of the NodeQueue and set "NodeQueue n" to itself minus the first element.

Answer (score 0):

You'd.. just.. do it.

```
public class Example {
    private int field;

    public int changeAndReturnSomething(int in) {
        this.field += in; //I changed a field...
        return in * 2; // and I return something!
    }
}
```

seems trivial.

Comment: But q is has a final attribute, I can change only with a constructor and length and first value are depending from q.

Comment: I would need to use a constructor to change everything, but I can't launch it in that method because I need the return value to be "first".

Comment: Methods can't return two things; your NodeList structure is immutable and thus cannot be updated. I guess you want a method that returns both the node removed as well as the new nodelist (with the removed node no longer in it). Returning 2 things from one method is tricky; I suggest you find another design. For example by not having an immutable data structure here.